# Why does visual studio mark all new classes as <Compile Remove /> in my csproj file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5

Whenever I add a new class to my project, visual studio adds and entry for it in the csproj file with
`<Compile Remove="<folder_path>\file.cs" />`

How can I stop it from doing that?

I have to go in and delete that entry for each file I add.

I have tried to set `EnableDefaultCompileItems` and `EnableDefaultItems` but those don't seem to fix this problem.

I have added some items in the csproj file as `<Content Include` and I'm wondering if that is triggering Visual Studio to remove anything new I add.

Comment: I would advise to recreate the project file. I assume that some setting/project type is wrong, and it thinks it should not compile CS files.

The Content Include should not have that effect.

Comment: I deleted all of my custom Content Include and it did fixed for me. Weird

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late, but maybe this helps someone someday.

The problem, as you may have noticed, is with the `<Content Include="Folder">`. If the file you're creating is inside the "Folder", Visual Studio will remove the item; not sure why, but it does.

To avoid this, you need to include the content more thoroughly, so, for example, if I want to include my images and sounds, I need to have:

```
<Content Include="Folder\Images\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="Folder\Sounds\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

This will avoid any new class to be removed if its created outside those included directories.